# Wordpress directory Permission for Plugins and Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to set permission for plugin directory to 554 because i am trying to set the permission for plugins directory and its files to 544 but its not loading the css and js files. same goes for themes .

Comment: You should set it to 644, not 544.

Comment: I've practically tested on my site to set permission to 544 and 555 and all plugins and css js still working. Do see my latest post below !!! thanks again for your question i followed and tried by myself.

Answer (score 2):

General rule of thumb: Folders set to 755 or 750. Files set to 644 or 640. Important files (wp-config.php) should have more strict permissions like 600.

See more [here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-file-permissions/).

Answer (score -1):

I supposed the author was asking how to set file permissions to reinforce wordpress security. Instead of default 644, 755 by wordpress installation, he wants to try some custom permission values while still want wordpress work normally.

Here is the official codex page reference about recommended wp permmisions which may also take it as a reference cause no one has concrete widely tested sample yet:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Furthermore,What i'd like to share with u is that 
while i'm studying on changing the chmod via diff approaches, i found my mozila ftp user unable to change the chmod first bit value,

case1 : folder chmod value 755 in ftp view panel (such as the image below)
[image]
when you use full control ftp account (generated via cpanel)rightclick to view
attribute 755 and key in the value 644 then save. 
the outcome is surprislying not 644, but 744 instead.

But in **ssh command** and **cpanel file panel** interface
will not have this kind of strange problem (1st bit didn't change) 
in the chmod pemmsion settings.

In addition, I've also tried setting up apache passwd protection to certain folder as a way to enhance wordpress security, such as in the practice of adding .htaccess and .htapsswd to make wp-admin a password protected restricted directory, however, i found it not successful to implement on share-hosting server.

Below is another post discussing about wordpress security involving configuration of chmod and plugin compatibilities.
url: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167900/evaluations-of-two-wordpress-security-plans-against-php-code-injection-attack/167905#167905

Thanks for this post and others' answer contributions :)

//2014 11 20 
live testing of setting folder and file permission to 555 554 respectively and confirmed, the plugin folder and css js inside still working very well.

// firstly after testing, i found the permission can be set more strict than nromal ones mentioned in wordpress documentation link and still run normally.

1. all *.php file can be set to 544 to avoid writing permission or prevent injection
2. for normal folders usually 555 is okay,"wp-upload" folder needs a 755.  if you set js, css to 544, you will get 404 error and of course they wouldn't be load, can set those folder to 555.
3. normally if you set the first bit to a stricter mode it's would not be able to use ftp software to modify, meaning if the file or folder has been set to 544, using ftp can not modify the chmod permission of the 1st bit. the complete modification should be using ssh or cpanel file management tools thus made the site files & folders more secure.